# Wildcard in jQuery selector for multidimensional select field

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a bunch of these select fields..

```
<select name="options[0][option_group_id]" />
<select name="options[1][option_group_id]" />
<select name="options[2][option_group_id]" />
<select name="options[new3][option_group_id]" />
```

I want to assign an onchange event like the following where \S is the wildcard for the keys 0,1,2,new3...:

```
<script>
$("select[name^='options[\\S*][option_group_id]']").live("change", function(){
  alert('Houston we have contact!');
});
</script>
```

But it does not work. What do I put to make it work?

Comment: Do you want to select them all? Why not just `$('select')`?

Comment: No, I want to identify them individually to perform a chained operation regarding the key identifier. That's another case.

Comment: By the way: `live` [is depreciated and being removed from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/live/). [You should be using `on()` instead](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: vzwick: Thanks alot for pointing that out. Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split it to 2 expressions: one for the beginning of the name, and another for its ending:

```
$('select[name^="options"][name$="[option_group_id]"]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/enZLu/

Comment: You made this look so amazingly easy! It works like a charm. I did not know you could combine expressions like that.

Comment: @tim: yeah, you can combine expressions as you want. `[name^="options"]` has nothing different with just `select`

Answer (score 2):

```
var pattern = /options\[\d{1,}\]\[option_group_id\]/;
$('select').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('name').match(pattern) !== null;
}).live(...
```

Comment: Upvoted for a great answer for solving wildcards. The answer by zerkms is most convenient for this particular example in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Depending on the performance sensitivity of your application, you might also want to take into consideration [this jsPerf benchmark.](http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-multiple-expressions) I totally agree though, that @zerkms version is much more readable and jQuery-like.

Comment: Using Chrome your solution was 20% faster than multiexpressions.